# getLongArrayExtra returning null

Tags: java, android, android-activity, arraylist

I am sending the ItemId after converting the List to array of type long and trying to retrieve in the List class but it the value is null. On Decoding I can see the value is being sent but the getLongArrayExtra is not working..

```
 List<Long> sList = new ArrayList<Long>();
 sList.add(1);
 sList.add(2);
 Long[] ItemId = sList.toArray(new Long[sList.size()]);
      Intent iIntent = new Intent(this, List.class);
      iIntent.putExtra("ITEM_ID", ItemId);

      startActivity(iIntent);


  final Intent intent = getIntent();
  long[]ItemIdList = intent.getLongArrayExtra("ITEM_ID");
```

Comment: is there an error in logcat? or just getting null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of toArray(Array)

Returns an array containing all elements contained in this
{@code ArrayList}. If the specified array is large enough to hold the
elements, the specified array is used, otherwise an array of the same
type is created. If the specified array is used and is larger than this
{@code ArrayList}, the array element following the collection elements
is set to null.

so what is happening in your case, the array you pass as the parameter in

```
Long[] ItemId = sList.toArray(new Long[sList.size()]);
```

Actually the new Long created there contains your data, as it has enough space to hold it, and the value returned is null.

what you should do is:

```
Long[] ItemId = new Long[sList.size()]);
sList.toArray(ItemId);
```

Comment: Thanks.. the new activity intent has the value but when getting it with getLongArrayExtra it is null. I did like you mentioned and it still shows null.

Answer (score 1):

FIXED: I found out the reason why it was null. The reason being that the type is Long while we are looking for "long". 
To solve this I need to convert it into primitive data type long.